# How to get the niid of all ttk.Treeview node with a certain tagname (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

How do I get the Node ID (i.e. `niid`) of all nodes in a `ttk.Treeview` with a certain tagname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the function `.tag_has(tag_name)`.

For example:

```py
...
columns = list(range(1,3))
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns)

tree.insert('', 'end', iid=1, values=(1,1), tags='1')
tree.insert('', 'end', iid=2, values=(2,2), tags='1')
tree.insert('', 'end', iid=3, values=(3,3), tags='3')
tree.insert('', 'end', iid=4, values=(4,4), tags='1')
tree.insert('', 'end', iid=5, values=(5,5), tags='2')

print(tree.tag_has('1'))
...
```

The output will be:

```
('1', '2', '4')
```